# Unable to authenticate with web scraper using Python - need help resolving login issue

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy

I'm currently working on a Python web scraper to extract data from MyFitnessPal (MFP) using the holtchesley/mfp_food_and_excercise GitHub repository as a reference (link: https://github.com/holtchesley/mfp_food_and_excercise). However, I'm facing difficulties when attempting to authenticate and log in to the MFP website programmatically. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this login issue.

Things I have done:

- I have ensured that the login credentials provided by the scraper are accurate and match the credentials used for manual login.
- I have debug the code and ensured that the date variables and url generated from it are correct. When I paste the url in my browser it takes me to the correct page.

The problem:

When the scraper tries to login with the credentials, it is redirected several times and it comes back to the login page.

1. 2023-05-18 16:32:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login?email=&username=prayagpurohit1%40gmail.com&password=**>](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login?email=&username=prayagpurohit1%40gmail.com&password=**%3E) (referer: https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login)
2. 2023-05-18 16:32:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET [https://www.myfitnesspal.com/reports/printable_diary?from=2023-03-24&to=2023-03-24>](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/reports/printable_diary?from=2023-03-24&to=2023-03-24%3E) from <GET [http://www.myfitnesspal.com/reports/printable_diary?from=2023-03-24&to=2023-03-24>](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/reports/printable_diary?from=2023-03-24&to=2023-03-24%3E)

*when I put the URL in the 2nd log directly, it opens the correct page (after logging in ofc)*

3. 2023-05-18 16:32:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myfitnesspal.com%2Freports%2Fprintable-diary%3Ffrom%3D2023-03-24%26to%3D2023-03-24>](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myfitnesspal.com%2Freports%2Fprintable-diary%3Ffrom%3D2023-03-24%26to%3D2023-03-24%3E) (referer: None)

The spider auto closes before scraping anything here. What is the problem here, you can refer the mfp.py file for more inspection and understanding the code.

```py
import os
import scrapy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser as dtparser


class MfpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "mfp"
 allowed_domains = ["myfitnesspal.com"]
 start_urls = (
     'https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login',
 )

 def __init__(self, username='', password='', start_date=None, target_date='', 
             target_file='', outdir='output', *args, **kwargs):
     super(MfpSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.username = username
     self.password = password
     self.target_date = target_date
     self.target_file = target_file
     self.outdir = outdir

     self.start_date = dtparser.parse(target_date)
     self.end_date = dtparser.parse(target_date)
     if start_date is not None:
         self.start_date = dtparser.parse(start_date)
     self.dts = self.get_dts()

 def get_dts(self):
     ndays = (self.end_date - self.start_date).days
     return [self.start_date + timedelta(i) for i in range(ndays + 1)]

 def parse(self, response):
     return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                             formdata={
                                                 'username': self.username,
                                                 'password': self.password},
                                             callback=self.logged_in)  # Login

 def logged_in(self, response):
     print('LOGGED IN. PROCESSING...')
     # print(response.body)
     for dt in self.dts:
         dtstr = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
         yield scrapy.Request(url="http://www.myfitnesspal.com/reports/printable_diary?from=" + dtstr + "&to=" + dtstr,
                              callback=self.dump_tables)  # Go to this URL after logging in which gives a diary for each date

 def write_table(self, rows, filename):
     with open(filename, "w") as f:
         f.write('\n'.join(rows))

 def get_outfile(self, name):
     return os.path.join(self.outdir, name + '.csv')

 def read_tables(self, response, name, delimiter='\t'):
     frmt = lambda x: delimiter.join(x).encode('UTF-8')  # + u"\n".encode('UTF-8')
     outputs = []
     for table in response.xpath("//table[@id='" + name + "']"):
         for row in table.xpath(".//tr"):
             contents = row.xpath("./td/text()").extract()
             outputs.append(frmt(contents))
     return outputs

 def dump_tables(self, response):
     # get data
     # print(response.body)
     dts = response.xpath('//h2/text()').extract()
     foods = self.read_tables(response, 'food')
     exercise = self.read_tables(response, 'exercise')  # n.b. the typo
     title = dtparser.parse(dts[0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if dts else ''

     # write data
     self.write_table(foods, self.get_outfile(title + "-food"))
     self.write_table(exercise, self.get_outfile(title + "-exercise"))
```

Comment: You need to add your code if you want help troubleshooting.

Comment: sounds like you might need a browser automation tool.